# Сортировка чисел карт в одномерном массиве

Tags: java

Изначально порядок карт в колоде (если перечислять карты сверху вниз) равен {100, 50, 60, 30}. Пупкин будет выполнять следующие действия:

1. достанет карту с числом 100 и поместит её вниз колоды, так как число, написанное на ней, не минимальное из оставшихся. Порядок карт в колоде после этого станет равным {50, 60, 30, 100}.
2. достанет карту с числом 50 и поместит её вниз колоды, так как число, написанное на ней, не минимальное из оставшихся. Порядок карт в колоде после этого станет равным {60, 30, 100, 50}.
3. достанет карту с числом 60 и поместит её вниз колоды, так как число, написанное на ней, не минимальное из оставшихся. Порядок карт в колоде после этого станет равным {30, 100, 50, 60}.
4. достанет карту с числом 30 и уберёт её, так как число, написанное на ней, минимальное из оставшихся. Порядок карт в колоде после этого станет равным {100, 50, 60}.
5. достанет карту с числом 100 и поместит её вниз колоды, так как число, написанное на ней, не минимальное из оставшихся. Порядок карт в колоде после этого станет равным {50, 60, 100}.
6. достанет карту с числом 50 и уберёт её, так как число, написанное на ней, минимальное из оставшихся. Порядок карт в колоде после этого станет равным {60, 100}.
7. достанет карту с числом 60 и уберёт её, так как число, написанное на ней, минимальное из оставшихся. Порядок карт в колоде после этого станет равным {100}.
8. достанет карту с числом 100 и уберёт её, так как число, написанное на ней, минимальное из оставшихся. После этого карт в колоде не останется.

Таким образом, Пупкин 8 раз посмотрит верхнюю карту колоды, чтобы отсортировать карты в ней.
Напишите код реализующий все это на Java SE. Использовать только одномерный массив, например:
 int array[] = {100, 50, 60, 30};
вот моя реализация, но не верная:

```
int array[] = new int[5]; 

array[0] = 100;
array[1] = 50;
array[2] = 60;
array[3] = 30;
array[4] = 101;

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    int min = array[i];  
    int imin = i; 

    for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
        if(min < array[j]){ 
            min = array[j];
            imin = j;
        }
    }
    if (i != imin) {
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[imin];
    array[imin] = temp;
}
System.out.print("  "+array[i]);        
}
```

Comment: Какие попытки в решении этого домашнего задания предпринимались?

Comment: пытался делать..пузырьковый и сортировочный массив.. не вышло. вот прошу помощи у людей кто может осилить эту задачу. Лично у меня не вышло. Я начинающий программист поэтому сюда и обратился. Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: Дайте мне немного времени, я уже пишу ответ.

Comment: _пытался делать..пузырьковый и сортировочный массив.. не вышло_ добавь код своих попыток, с указанием что именно не вышло

Comment: Хорошо, как объявить массив в Java? Как можно узнать длину массива (количество элементов в массиве)? Как организовать цикл в Java? Как обратиться к элементу массива по индексу? Если уважаемый автор знает ответы, возможно, кто-то решит помочь ему.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian вроде открыт. отредактировал вопрос . пишите свой вариант. так как на своем я остановился и не понимаю, как и что дальше писать так что бы было как описано в задании.

Comment: @AndreyKonstantinovich, Во-первых не тыкайте. Во-вторых уважительно  относитесь к другим участникам сообщества, это те люди, которые могут вам помочь, если вы будете вести себя в соответствии с нашими правилами: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange . Считайте это предупреждением.

Comment: @AndreyKonstantinovich, Еще раз повторю.  Дело не в сути вопроса.  В исходном виде вопрос нарушал **правила нашего сообщества**, т.к. не содержал **ваших** попыток решения. Я его закрыл. Вы привели его в соответствие правилам. Я его переоткрыл. Сейчас вы зачем-то продолжаете выплескивать агрессию.

Comment: @Nofate агрессию? мне кажется у вас ее докучи! удаляйте мой вопрос. я на этот сайт не зайду. раз тут такое. до свидания! и правильно что тут написано на баннерах - глупых вопросов не бывает, а только глупые ответы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может и не оптимально, но требуемое поведение выполняет.

```
public class Deck {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int deck[] = {100,50,60,30};

        // Мы не знаем сколько карт в колоде, не знаем, какая карта младшая (подлежащая удалению).

        // Узнаем, сколько карт в колоде.
        int length = deck.length;
        // Сделаем предположение, что первая карта в колоде - младшая.
        int lowCard = deck[0];

        // Узнаем минимальное число в колоде перед началом действий.
        for(int card: deck){
            lowCard = card <= lowCard ? card : lowCard;
        }

        // А теперь пристумим к действиям от лица Пупкина.
        while(deck[0] != 0){
            System.out.println("Достал " + deck[0]);
            if(deck[0] <= lowCard){
                System.out.println("Удаляю " + deck[0]);
                deck[0] = 0;
                // Предположим, что следующей младшей картой будет следующая карта в колоде.
                if(length > 1){
                    lowCard = deck[1] != 0 ? deck[1] : 0;
                }
                // Если карта младшая - удаляем её (заменяем на 0 и помещаем в конец массива в данном случае).
                for(int i = 0; i < length-1 ; i++){
                    // Параллельно ищем новую минимальную карту.
                    lowCard = (deck[i] != 0 && deck[i] <= lowCard) ? deck[i] : lowCard;
                    deck[i] = deck[i+1];
                }
                deck[length-1] = 0;
                if(length > 0) length--;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Убираю на дно " + deck[0]);
                int rememberCard = deck[0];
                for(int i = 0; i < length-1 ; i++){
                    deck[i] = deck[i+1];
                }
                deck[length-1] = rememberCard;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все работает так как задумано в задачке! Спасибо огромное, что ответили.. хоть я уже и забил на нее. но интересно будет посмотреть как оно работает в коде . еще раз спаибо за адекватный ответ на мой вопрос